# Accesing member items of NSDictionary inside an NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I did a query to the Flickr API and It returned me with an NSArray containing dictionaries. I was wondering how i might be able to access lets the _content item of the array that was sent back to me.

```
  NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
NSLog(@"%@",topPlaces);

(
    {
    "_content" = "London, England, United Kingdom";
    latitude = "51.506";
    longitude = "-0.127";
    "photo_count" = 3061;
    "place_id" = "hP_s5s9VVr5Qcg";
    "place_type" = locality;
    "place_type_id" = 7;
    "place_url" = "/United+Kingdom/England/London";
    timezone = "Europe/London";
    woeid = 44418;
},
    {
    "_content" = "New York, NY, United States";
    latitude = "40.714";
    longitude = "-74.007";
    "photo_count" = 1886;
    "place_id" = ".skCPTpTVr.Q3WKW";
    "place_type" = locality;
    "place_type_id" = 7;
    "place_url" = "/United+States/New+York/New+York";
    timezone = "America/New_York";
    woeid = 2459115;
},
    {
    "_content" = "Weston-Super-Mare, England, United Kingdom";
    latitude = "51.346";
    longitude = "-2.977";
    "photo_count" = 945;
    "place_id" = HWdHmQdVUrptMA;
    "place_type" = locality;
    "place_type_id" = 7;
    "place_url" = "/United+Kingdom/England/Weston-Super-Mare";
    timezone = "Europe/London";
    woeid = 40016;
},
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the NSArray like so

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in topPlaces) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"_content"]);
}
```